# JavaScript Function arguments

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a function that deserialises a JSON object and creates some functions, but I want to be able to specify a variable set of arguments.

For example, in JSON I want to specify something like:

```
{
  "handler" :
  {
    "args" : ["evt","value"],
    "content" : "console.log(value);"
  }
}
```

And when I parse the object, I will do something like:

```
var myFunction = new Function(handler.args,handler.content);
```

But the challenge is that each argument is supposed to be a *n* strings followed by the content of the function as the last argument.  Is there any easy way of specifying *n* number of arguments in a `new Function()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

> **Parameters**
>
> **arg1, arg2, ... argN**
>
> > Names to be used by the function as formal argument names. Each must be
> >     a string that corresponds to a valid
> >     JavaScript identifier or a list of
> >     such strings separated with a comma;
> >     **for example "x", "theValue", or "a,b"**.

So the arguments list can either be one or more strings seperated by commas, or just one string with each identifier in it seperated by commas.

Also since

```
['evt', 'value'].toString() == 'evt,value'
```

Simply passing your `handler.args` array as the first argument to the `new Function` constructor should work exactly as you want it to

```
new Function(handler.args, handler.content);
```

Internally, `new Function` casts every argument to a string if it is not already one. So conceivably something like this would also work

```
new Function({ toString: function() { return 'a,b,c' } }, 'return a+b+c');
```

Not that I'm suggesting you do anything silly like that.

This works in every browser I've tried including IE

Comment: I don't think this will work. `new Function('evt, value', handler.content);` is different than `new Function('evt', 'value' , handler.content);` I don't think `Function` calls `split(',')` on its arguments. And `evt, value` by itself is an invalid parameter name (will, it will be interpreted as two parameters). But you cannot conclude that it having a *string* in this format has the same effect.

Comment: @Felix Kling - It most certainly does work, because the *MDN documentation said it would*. Regardless of how it works internally, the docs clearly say `'a','b'` is interpreted the same way as `'a,b'`. I can conclude exactly what I said, because I've tried it and it works. Why don't you [try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ8K3/)?

Comment: Actually, I was going for Felix's answer, but in this particular instance, this works out cleaner for me in my code, so I am going to accept this one.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

To solve the technically issue: You can use [**`apply`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
handler.args.push(handler.content);
var myFunction = Function.apply(null, handler.args);
```

However the question is why you are doing something like this? What is the context? Spontaneously I would say you should consider another solution for whatever problem you are trying to solve ;)

Comment: This calls the function immediately, OP is asking how to use the function constructor to generate a function

Comment: @JuanMendes: ? This calls the function constructor. `Function(a, b, c)` is the same as `Function.apply(null, [a, b, c])`.

Comment: sorry, I did misread the code. I'm still trying to figure out what OP means by the question

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest route would be to combine the 2 properties. Then use `apply` to construct the function.

```
var x = {
  "handler" :
  {
    "constructorArgs" : [
        "evt",
        "value",
        "alert(value);"
    ]
  }
};

var f = Function.apply(undefined, x.handler.constructorArgs);
f(1, 2);
```

To keep it similar you can use `Array.prototype.concat`.

```
var x = {
  "handler" :
  {
      args: [ "evt", "value" ],
      content : "alert(value);"
  }
};

var f = Function.apply(undefined, x.handler.args.concat(x.handler.content));
f(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can;t you just make the body of your functions work with the arguments property?

http://jsfiddle.net/9XcEb/

```
var add = new Function(
    "var total=0;"+
    "for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {"+
       "total+=arguments[i]"+
    "};"+
    " return total"
);

alert(add(3,4,5,6));
```